# "gamedb is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So everything worked fine like 5 minutes ago and then when i went afk for like 15 minutes and try debugging the code i get this error: "gamedb is not defined"
This is basically it.. Is there anything wrong with port forwarding or with ip or something like that?

Code at user.js

```
module.exports = User = gamedb.model('User', userSchema);
```

and code at config.js:

```
    var args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var extend = require('extend');

var environment = args.env || "test";

var common_conf = {
    name : "Tonijev virtualni svet",
    version : "0.0.1",
    environment : environment,
    max_player : 100,
    data_paths : {
        items: __dirname + "\\Game Data\\" + "Items\\",
        maps: __dirname + "\\Game Data\\" + "Maps\\"
    },
    starting_zone: "startHisa"
};

var conf = {
    production: {
        ip: args.ip || "0.0.0.0",
        port: args.port || 8022,
        database: "mongodb://127.0.0.1/tonisvet_prod"
        },
    test: {
        ip: args.ip || "0.0.0.0",
        port: args.port || 8021,
        database: "mongodb://127.0.0.1/tonisvet_test"
    }
};

extend(false,conf.production,common_conf);
extend(false,conf.test,common_conf);

module.exports = config = conf[environment];
```

I use node.js and mongodb for database

EDIT:

i forgot to add the code at mongodb.js:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = gamedb = mongoose.createConnection(config.database);
```

Comment: Seems like there's a line missing at User.js file which defined `gamedb`. If it was working, probably it was there and you might have accidentally deleted it. Check your version control, or the file history from your IDE if it has it.

Comment: Everything is the same checked it 10 times :/

Comment: Seems like the code your missing is `var gamedb = require('./mongodb');`

Comment: That makes perfect sense and it works! But something is weird becouse i never had this code in my user.js file and it worked before... Still thanks for help!